# Creating symbolic matrix in MATLAB or Mathematica

Tags: matlab, mathematica-8

Is it possible to define an **m** by **m** matrix (m is a symbolic integer) with say **m/(m+1)** as its diagonal elements and **-1/m** as its off-diagonal elements in MATLAB or Mathematica?

Let me give more explanations: Suppose you are asked to find the inverse [determinant, eigenvalues etc.] of a **m** by **m** matrix as I defined above [e.g. it is not difficult to show that the inverse of such a matrix is a **m** by **m** matrix with **2** in its diagonal and **1** in off-diagonal]. Is it possible to use MATLAB or any other software to answer such questions?

Comment: The solution by @Rafael is for MATLAB.

Comment: How can one create a matrix if its size is not known? (a symbol) ??  How many rows will it have? how many columns?  You want matrix with `m` rows and `m` columns when `m` has no numerical value? The content of the matrix can be symbolic, but not the size? Can you show an example of what you want? Say for `m` by `m` symbolic matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
m = 4; % Or any other positive integer
matrix = eye(m) * (m/(m+1)) + (1 - eye(m)) * (-1/m)
```

Comment: Technically this is a numeric matrix, not a symbolic matrix as requested by the OP in the question title.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an actual "symbolic" matrix, in Matlab you'll need to use a bit of the [Symbolic Math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012b/symbolic/getting-started-with-symbolic-math-toolbox.html):

```
m = 7;
ms = sym(m);
mat = -ones(m)/ms;
mat(1:m+1:end) = ms/(ms+1);
```

which returns

```
mat =

[  7/8, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7]
[ -1/7,  7/8, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7]
[ -1/7, -1/7,  7/8, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7]
[ -1/7, -1/7, -1/7,  7/8, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7]
[ -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7,  7/8, -1/7, -1/7]
[ -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7,  7/8, -1/7]
[ -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7, -1/7,  7/8]
```

Mathematica-related questions are best addressed at the dedicated [Mathematica.StackExchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It seems that I wasn't clear enough in my question. I am not looking for a matrix with a specific numeric value for m. What I want is to create a symbolic matrix which has m rows and m columns with m/(m+1) in its diagonal and -1/m in off-diagonals where m is a symbolic integer.

Comment: @user41838: the terms "numeric" and "symbolic" have specific meanings in Matlab related to the `class` of a variable. Floating-point class variables are numeric – for example: `a=eye(3);` `class(a)` `isnumeric(a)`. However, `b=sym(a);` `class(b)` `isnumeric(b)`.